# Blurry screen transition when having gradient as background

Tags: android, animation, gradient, android-constraintlayout

I've got a situation where **both** of my screens have a gradient as background, using an android.transition.Fade() as enter/exist transition between them.

While the animation is running and the screen is rendering, for a noticeable period (like half a second), the screen (only the fragment container) is blurring and then it fixes itself

[image: blurry image]

As you can see, the buttons are blurred (which are behind the player bar in a different fragment). The layout is as simple as possible, even tho there are a lot of views and lists, the layout is not overcomplicated with unnecessary views

This is the gradient i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="315"
        android:endColor="#0D0D0D"
        android:startColor="#46393F"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```